# Osmand build crash on debug

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I imported the latest master folder `(master branch 26-12-2014)` to `Android-Studio,Gradle build` the project successfully after little fix (`asset missing,inner fragment static error`) then i launched the debugger on my device (`samsung galaxy 3 min,Android 4.1.2`),I expect to have `Osmand running on my device` but the application `crashes and the log indicate` that it happen on getting `routing.xml` file.

```
12-26 10:47:10.069  10508-10508/net.osmand.plus E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application net.osmand.plus.OsmandApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4200)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at net.osmand.router.RoutingConfiguration.getDefault(RoutingConfiguration.java:171)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.getBuilder(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:44)
            at net.osmand.plus.helpers.AvoidSpecificRoads.<init>(AvoidSpecificRoads.java:38)
            at net.osmand.plus.OsmandApplication.onCreate(OsmandApplication.java:168)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is a folder named "router" inside your "OsmAnd/scr/net/osmand/" folder which contains the routing.xml file.

If not you can find the resources needed [here](https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd-resources)